# Windows Phone 8.1: How to display Html

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I've a windows phone 8.1 and there I will show some html code.

The html code is like this:

```
<div><label>Hallo</label></div>.
```

So which is the best xaml control to display this html?

I tried this WebView, but it make me not that happy. Is there a other possibility?

Thanks

Comment: Why were you unhappy?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other platforms there is no native control that can render HTML as text. (Formatted or otherwise.)

As you've discovered, WebView isn't appropriate as it's designed to show whole web pages, not small snippets of HTML.

A number of people have attempted to write utilities or controls to perform the conversion. In terms of trying out what's available, I suggest you start with http://winrthtml2xaml.codeplex.com/ as this was written specifically for WinRT and so should best suit your needs in terms of creating appropriate XAML.

Only if you're working with a small, defined set of HTML tags would I even consider writing something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

WebView is obviously the choice number one if you need to keep the formatting (that means that you want to keep the links, paragraphs etc. and not just strip down HTML tags and use plain text), but there's another little known control called HTML TextBlock which was written for Windows Phone 7, but probably could be used or slightly modified to fit Windows Phone 8.1

More info can be found on [CodePlex homepage of the project](http://krempelwp7.codeplex.com/) and [the author's blog](http://thewp7dev.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/html-textblock/).

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately There is no other control like `Webview` that can help you out to Load `HTML`. You Should go for it.